# Run executable with parameters in range using CMD

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I need to execute the same program multiple times but with different parameters each time.
So I created a batch file which loops and calls this program. the batch looks like this:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (5,1,15) DO program.exe -t %%G
```

Now I have the same program, but I also want to send it some more parameters on each call, which will be the numbers from 0 to %%G/2.

For example, for %%G being 10, I want to run the program with the parameters:

```
program.exe -t 10 -s 0 1 2 3 4
```

Can this be done in some way in windows batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: first way - use a subroutine

FOR /L %%G IN (5,1,15) DO CALL :sub %%G

:: second way - use "delayedexpansion"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /L %%G IN (5,1,15) DO (
 SET /a parm2=%%G / 2
 FOR /L %%T IN (2,1,!parm2!) DO ECHO(second way %%G %%T
)

GOTO :EOF

:sub
SET /a parm2=%1 / 2
FOR /L %%T IN (2,1,%parm2%) DO ECHO(first  way %1 %%T

GOTO :EOF
```

The first way uses a subroutine which calculates the second parameter from the first parameter that ***it*** is passed, `%1` to the subroutine; `%%G` to the main routine

The second way uses delayed expansion, which allows `!var!` to be used to access the variable `parm2` as it is changed by operation of the loop. `%parm2%` would be replaced by the value of `parm2` before the loop began. (see any number of SO items about `delayedexpansion`)

---

After clarification...

```dos
:: use "delayedexpansion"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /L %%G IN (5,1,15) DO (
 SET "paramstr="
 SET /a parm2=%%G / 2
 FOR /L %%T IN (0,1,!parm2!) DO SET "paramstr=!paramstr! %%T"
 ECHO(program.exe %%G !paramstr!
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This accumulates the required range into `paramstr` using delayed expansion

Comment: Thanks, but this will run the program each time with different variable. I want to sent it all the numbers between 0 and `%%G/2`.  so what you proposed will print (for %%G=10): way 10 0, way 10 1 and so on. while i want it to print: way 10 0 1 2 3 4